# Can't extract a value out of HTML with lxml

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, lxml

I have this piece of HTML (numbers differ):

`<span class="ng-binding">
    <b>Total:</b> 
    68.71€ (459 items)
</span>`

---

Out of this i want to extract the `68.71€ (459 items)`

---

I tried doing it with this piece of Code so far and just copied the xpath to the span class shown above right out of Google Chrome:

```
import urllib.request
from lxml import html
import os

ids =  ["ftpstorage1-730",
        "ftpstorage2-730",
        "ftpstorage3-730"]

for id in ids:

url = 'http://steam.tools/itemvalue/#/'+id
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
    site = response.read()
    tree = html.fromstring(site)
    data = tree.xpath('//*[@id="container"]/div[5]/span[1]/text()')

    print(data)
```

In theory this should work but it won't, all i do get as `data` is:

```
[" {{(items | filter:dupesFilter | filter:typeFilter | filter:filterText |   sumByKey:'price':'count':
e}}\n\t\t\t\t({{items | filter:dupesFilter | filter:typeFilter |    filter:filterText | sumByKey:'count
[" {{(items | filter:dupesFilter | filter:typeFilter | filter:filterText | sumByKey:'price':'count':
e}}\n\t\t\t\t({{items | filter:dupesFilter | filter:typeFilter | filter:filterText | sumByKey:'count
[" {{(items | filter:dupesFilter | filter:typeFilter | filter:filterText | sumByKey:'price':'count':
e}}\n\t\t\t\t({{items | filter:dupesFilter | filter:typeFilter | filter:filterText | sumByKey:'count
```

---

any idea what i'm doing wrong?

does it have something to do with the numbers being generated and not being static?

If so, how can i still extract the numbers?

Comment: The data is not in the source, it is dynamically generated

Comment: @PadraicCunningham bonus points if you get the totals via `requests`. :)

Comment: @alecxe, you beat me to it!

Comment: @PadraicCunningham sorry, at first I thought about selenium, but then I realized I can try beat you here :)

Comment: @alecxe, well Angular is definitely more up your street than mine so I was always in danger here ;) Still serious bonus points available for http://www.flashscore.com/ ...

Comment: @PadraicCunningham okay, thanks, but I would need to drink something strong to approach that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see printed on the console is the *unrendered HTML with AngularJS binding placeholders*. You need a real browser to execute javascript and let Angular put the real values into the placeholders.

Or, you can solve it without having to use a real browser, if you go deeper into how the total price is retrieved and calculated. Make a GET request to the `http://item-value10.appspot.com/ParseInv` endpoint providing the `id` and `app` parameters, parse the JSON response and calculate the price taking into the account the item count:

```
import requests


template_url = "http://item-value10.appspot.com/ParseInv"
ids = ["ftpstorage1-730", "ftpstorage2-730", "ftpstorage3-730"]

for id in ids:
    with requests.Session() as session:
        session.get('http://steam.tools/itemvalue/#/' + id)

        storage, app = id.split("-")
        url = template_url.format(storage=storage, app=app)

        response = session.get(url, params={
            "id": storage,
            "app": app
        }, headers={
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36",
            "Referer": "http://steam.tools/itemvalue/"
        })

        data = response.json()
        total = sum(float(item["price"]) * int(item["count"]) for item in data["items"])
        print(total)
```

Prints:

```
20.439999999999998
78.16
0
```

Comment: @alecxe holy damn that's a beautiful awnser, thanks alot, exactly what i wanted and i also understood the idea behind it.

Comment: @alexce i have a simple follow-up question, i just noticed these numbers are dollar and not euro, do i have to manually convert them or is there a way to get them requested?

Comment: @Lyux you should make a request to http://cdn.steam.tools/data/currency.json and get the conversion coefficient, then adjust the price accordingly. Thanks.